# Are there any way to link my program with Wine-compiled part?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, wine

I am trying to use windows dll functionality in Linux.
My current solution is a compilation of a separate wine application, that uses dll and transfer requests/responses between dll and main application over IPC.

This works, but is a real overhead comparing to a simple dll calls.

I see that wine-compiled program usually is a bootstrapping-script and some .so, which (according to *file* utility) is normal linux dynamically linked library.

Are there any way to link that .so directly to my application? Are there any manual?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be able to use [Winelib](http://www.winehq.org/winelib) to write a Linux app that can use Windows DLLs.

**EDIT:**

For future reference:

`libtest.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  HMODULE h;

  h = LoadLibrary("cards.dll");
  printf("%d\n", h);
}
```

Execution:

```
$ winegcc -m32 libtest.c 
$ ./a.out
536936448
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything that helped achieve my goal.

Comment: Not even the `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions in wine/windows/winbase.h?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right - I could compile program like your example before, now I've tried simply make a library of it and compile to the main application - and it works. Tried this without loading dll by now, but in general it works. Thanks.

Comment: If you get: `fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory`, install wine1.6-dev package.