# using win32 api in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, porting

I have heard of WINE but I don't like it because it's slow on the computers I have tested and almost always crashes. It also has some unpleasant looking gui.
I am wondering if there is a "win32" library in c/c++ for linux that produces **native linux code**
so that if I have my source code for windows, I can just recompile and produce a working linux application. Is this possible?

Comment: Would you call it wincyg, or cyglin?

Comment: What windows functions would you need? The reason wine is slow / buggy for some of them is that there are millions and wine concentrates on those most used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Winelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617468/are-there-any-way-to-link-my-program-with-wine-compiled-part/2617558#2617558).

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a portable library, e.g. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Comment: yes, I have heard of qt. But as far as i know , it does not support win32 calls. Like most programmers i wonder if it is possible to avoid learning a new api for graphics

Comment: @stakx: I agree, but native APIs aren't designed to be portable. If he wants to write code which will result in native executables on Windows and Linux with a good-looking UI, he has to use something else.

Comment: +1 These portable libraries will also make it possible to compile your program for Mac. For a C++ programmer, these libraries are well worth the trouble to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will find something that complete.
But if you look for something that provides some windows API under Linux then look at:
[windows to linux port library](http://www.adontec.com/windows-to-linux-port-library.htm)