# Ubuntu 13.04: No windows.h found for winegcc?

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I'm trying to compile a very simple C file with winegcc that utilizes `#include <windows.h>`

The compilation fails because it cannot find windows.h

The code is nearly identical to a prior stackoverflow post, viz:

[Are there any way to link my program with Wine-compiled part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617468/are-there-any-way-to-link-my-program-with-wine-compiled-part/2617558#2617558)

I installed wine on Ubuntu 13.04 using:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
    sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

The source file is nxwrap.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    int main(int argc,char **argv){

     HMODULE h;

     h = LoadLibrary("NxCoreAPI64a.dll");

     printf("%d\n",h);

     return 1;
    }
```

Going for an a.out, the command line call is:

```
    $ winegcc nxwrap.c
    nxwrap.c:2:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    winegcc: gcc failed
```

`locate` from the command line cannot find the `<windows.h>` system header anywhere on the FS.

Is there an additional ubuntu package that I have to install for wine dev?  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is adequately about programming or more about Ubuntu. I'm going to recommend you cross-post this at [AskUbuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com).

Comment: Thanks. The AskUbuntu answer was to install an additional dev package (wine1.6-dev to be exact).

Answer (score 3):

The AskUbuntu answer was to install an additional dev package (wine1.6-dev to be exact).